# Incorrect headers stop chrome from looping HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, webserver

I have been having a very strange and seemingly unlikely problem. I made a custom python server based off of SimpleHTTPServer, which requires me to set all my own headers. I started using it to serve .wav files and while they would play in an HTML5  tag in chrome they would *not* replay (via setting currentTime=0 and calling play() again). If I hosted them on standard Apache server, however, they would replay just fine. I open dev tools and slowly added and removed headers to my python server until they started playing properly. It turns out that the missing element was the "Accept-Ranges: bytes" header. Without it the wav file will not replay and with it everything works fine. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this same thing -- browsers require the `Accept-Ranges` header when playing audio via the `<audio>` tag. In my case, this was happening with MP3s (I didn't try with WAVs).

I don't know why that happens, but if you want to avoid it, use the new Web Audio API. In my experience, Chrome/Safari/Firefox will play (and replay) audio just fine without the `Accept-Ranges` header if you use the Web Audio API. Here's [a good starter article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).